# Reading data from old external drive that doesn't show up in diskutil list

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, usb

I have a seagate drive that put family photos on in 2013. I have it plugged in to my new macbook pro and the lights are on. It doesn't show up in disk utility or in `diskutil list` in the terminal, but it do see that it's connected in the Hardware/USB section of the system report. I'm a developer and I'm good with zsh etc. Is there a way for me to pull data from it in the terminal?

Comment: Sounds like the controller is working but the physical drive has failed. Do you hear it spinning? Or clicking?

Comment: And if the drive spins up it is likely the electronics. Many years ago I 'repaired" a drive by taking the circuit board from an identical drive and putting it on the defective drive. It allowed me to get the data off the defective drive. I put the circuit board back and the tossed the defective drive. Assuming you can do that (a big but) it may be worth the try, otherwise you may have to send it off to a data recovery specialist.

Comment: @SolarMike yeah I hear it spin just fine. Yeah I think it's time to take it in.